# Create a template that is a vector of a custom data type with multiple variables

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

I must be able to use the command below where T can be any type, such as string.

```
Counter<T> counter;
```

Counter should be able to hold multiple items so I have chosen to implement this as a vector. Each item must itself consist of a variable of type T (so a string if we continue the above example) and an int. I need to keep the solution as simple as possible as later on I will need to create functions that print out each item by descending int value amongst other tasks. I have had a go with the following code but 1) it doesn't work and 2) is there a better solution?

```
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>

template<class T>
class Record{
      T itemtype;
      int total;   
   public:
      int increment(T item);
      int count(T item);
      void printSummary();
};


class Counter{
      vector<Record> data;
};

int main(){

   Counter<string> counter;   

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Whell we can't see the implementation of Record moreover you use Counter as a template class but actually **it's not a template** and you don't specify the template argument for Record...

Comment: Counter class should be template too.

Comment: @Drew Dormann $ g++ Counter2.h -o Counter2
Counter2.h:17:7: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
Counter2.h: In function ‘int main()’:
Counter2.h:22:4: error: ‘Counter’ is not a template
Counter2.h:22:12: error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope
Counter2.h:22:12: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/stringfwd.h:65:33: note:   ‘std::string’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program contains a few mistakes, pointed out below.

**Minor issue:**

First of all, a minor thing: you don't need to include the `<cstdlib>` header - at least not for what you are showing.

```
#include<string>
// #include<cstdlib> // <== (YOU DON'T SEEM TO NEED THIS)
#include<vector>
```

**First problem:**

If you use unqualified names to refer to objects that live in a namespace, you should first have a `using` declaration that lets the compiler resolve those unqualified names to the correct fully qualified names (i.e. including the namespace they belong to).

For instance, `vector` and `string` belong to the `std` namespace. Thus, either you use those names in fully qualified form (`std::vector` and `std::string`), or you add proper `using` declarations, as done below:

```
using std::vector; // USING DECLARATIONS TO ALLOW UNQUALIFIED NAMES SUCH AS
using std::string; // string AND vector TO BE CORRECTLY RESOLVED
```

**Second problem:**

Finally, what you want is to make your class `Counter` parameterized, and that parameter should be used for instantiating the internal `vector`. Therefore, `Counter` must also be a class template (that's how you are using it in your `main()` function, after all):

```
// MAKE THIS A CLASS TEMPLATE!
template<typename T>
class Counter{
      vector<Record<T>> data;
};
```

**Conclusion:**

After all the above corrections have been implemented, this is how your code should look like:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

template<class T>
class Record{
      T itemtype;
      int total;   
   public:
      int increment(T item);
      int count(T item);
      void printSummary();
};

template<typename T>
class Counter{
      vector<Record<T>> data;
};

int main(){

   Counter<string> counter;   

   return 0;
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24153) showing the above piece of code compiling.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. How would I access each itemtype and total? eg if(Record.itemtype.count(item == 0){
      Record.push_back(itemtype = item, Record.total = 1);
   }

Comment: @user1905552: Like for all classes, you need an object of that class in order to access its members. Class templates are no exception. So you can't do `Record.itemtype`, because `Record` is the name of a class (template), not of an object. You can do, however (`Record<string> myRecord; myRecord.itemtype = 0;` etc.)

Comment: `template<class T>
int Counter <T> :: increment(T item){
   if(data.count(data.itemtype == 0)){
      data.push_back(data.itemtype = item, data.total = 1);
   }else{
      for(int i=0; i < data.size(data.itemtype); i++){
         if(data[i].itemtype == item){
            data[i].total = data[i].total + 1;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}` what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @user1905552: `increment()` is a member function of `Record`, not of the `Counter` class template

Comment: sorry I moved `increment()` to `Counter`

Comment: @user1905552: OK, but then you should show the updated code. How am I going to guess what you have in your class definitions, if you silently change them? Moreover, judging from your profile, it seems you are not marking as accepted any of the answers people give to your questions. SO is not a helpdesk where people spend their time doing your homework for no reason and for free. You should consider at least accepting correct or helpful answers. Then, if you have *new* questions after those answers have fixed some problem of yours... well, in that case just post a new question :)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I had changed the class definitions. I appreciate all your help and advice including tips on general use of stack overflow.

Comment: I have written up this second question, can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949202/accessing-variables-in-a-template-that-is-a-vector-of-a-custom-data-type-with-mu

Comment: @user1905552: It is not easy to understand what you are trying to do. It is visible that there are a lot of things you are confused about. I suggest getting yourself a good book on C++ and starting from the basics. Templates are advanced concepts. I don't say this to mean "I don't care", I'm saying it because it's the right advice. Even if someone came and fixed your program, you still wouldn't understand what's going on, and next time you wouldn't be able to solve a slightly different problem.

Answer (score 2):

You got it wrong, you need to make `Counter` parameterizable:

```
template <typename T>
class Counter{
      vector<Record<T> > data;
};
```

Of course, this means that all records in your `counter` will contain strings.

If "Counter should be able to hold multiple items" really means that one instance of `Counter` should contain various types or records (e.g. both strings and ints) then you need to use something like [`VARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) or something similar depending on your requirements and technology that you use, e.g.

```
Counter<boost::any> counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this:

```
template<class T>
class Record{
      T itemtype;
      int total;   
   public:
      int increment(T item);
      int count(T item);
      void printSummary();
};

template<class RECORDTYPE>
class Counter{
      vector<Record<RECORDTYPE>> data;
};

int main(){

   Counter<string> counter;   

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, does it make a difference if I use T in both templates?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's just a template parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

`Record` is a template so you cannot just have `vector<Record>` you must have a vector of a type of record, i.e. `vector<Record<T> >`