# Accessing variables in a template that is a vector of a custom data type with multiple variables

Tags: c++, function, templates, vector, stl

How do I access the variables `itemtype` and `total` within the `increment` function? The code I have below gives me errors as follows

Counter2.h: In member function ‘int Counter::increment(T)’:

Counter2.h:28:31: error: ‘itemtype’ was not declared in this scope

Counter2.h:36:22: error: ‘itemtype’ was not declared in this scope

Counter2.h:36:39: error: ‘total’ was not declared in this scope

I must be able to use the command `Counter<T> counter;` where T can be any type, such as string and `counter.increment()`

```
#include<string>
//#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

template<class T>
class Record{
   public:
      T itemtype;
      int total;   
};

template<class T>
class Counter{
      vector< Record<T> > data;
   public:
      int increment(T item);
      int count(T item);
      void printSummary();
};

template<class T>
int Counter <T> :: increment(T item){
   bool check = false;

   for(int i=0; i < data.size(itemtype); i++){
      if(data[i].itemtype == item){
         data[i].total++;
         bool check = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if(check == false){
      data.push_back(itemtype = item, total = 1);
   }
}

int main(){

   Counter<string> counter;   

   counter.increment("orange");
   counter.increment("orange");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line `for(int i=0; i < data.size(itemtype); i++){`

will be: `for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){`

And `data.push_back(itemtype = item, total = 1);` can be:

1. `data.push_back({item, 1}); // by using initializer list ; C++11`
2. or,

   ```
   Record r; 
   r.itemtype = item; 
   r.total = 1;
   data.push_back(r);
   ```

You can look at : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
to know about std::vector.

Comment: Cool thanks, just out of interest how long have you been working with c++ for?

Comment: Between 1 and 2 years may be.

Comment: hu-ju, but you omit the "insignificant" fact that your instructor was Professor Bjarne Stroustrup. Is that true?

Comment: It is true. How do you know that?

Comment: Congraulaiations! Amazing :-) That is what http is about: follow the links. SO-your profile-your site. He was my "Instructor" too... but only with the books, starting from 1990 I think, with the annotated c++ reference manual or so. Nevertheless I think making Record members public was not a big idea.

Comment: So, how would you justify why it wasn't.

Comment: I think Record is only one implementation detail need for one of the posibles implementations of Counter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I understand what you're after here, though for a start you're trying to access private members of class Record. You could make record a struct (public by default), or provide getters/setters or alternatively add:

```
friend class Counter;
```

to Record so that Counter can access its private members.

Comment: I have these errors but I don't know what they mean `Counter2.h:26:4: error: ‘class std::vector<Record<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<Record<std::basic_string<char> > > >’ has no member named ‘count’
Counter2.h:26:4: error: ‘class std::vector<Record<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<Record<std::basic_string<char> > > >’ has no member named ‘itemtype’
Counter2.h:27:7: error: ‘class std::vector<Record<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<Record<std::basic_string<char> > > >’ has no member named ‘itemtype’`

Comment: The vector class does not have a count method, or an itemtype field, basically. Hence why I said I wasn't sure what you were after.

Comment: thanks I didn't realise `count()` was not a method for vectors and have changed the example but I still get errors related to accessing the variables $ g++ Counter2.h -o Counter2
Counter2.h: In member function ‘int Counter<T>::increment(T)’:
Counter2.h:28:31: error: ‘itemtype’ was not declared in this scope
Counter2.h:36:22: error: ‘itemtype’ was not declared in this scope
Counter2.h:36:39: error: ‘total’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: That would be because you have no enclosing Record object that you're pushing to vector. I recommend making a constructor in Record:
Record(T itemtype, int total) { this->itemtype = itemtype; this->total = total; } 
Then you can do this:
data.push_back( Record(item, 1) );

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Record` a private structur inside `Counter`. That will not expose it implementation. You need to change also how you acces `data`. It is a `vector` of `Record`, not a `Record`. Something like:

```
template<class T>
class Counter
{
    struct Record{   T itemtype;    int total;      };
    vector< Record > data;
   public:
      int increment(const T& item);
      int count(const T& item);
      void printSummary();
};
template<class T>
int Counter <T> :: increment(const T& item)
{
   auto i=data.begin();
   i= find(i,data.end(),[&item](const Record& r)
                        {return item==r.itemtype;});
   if (i!=data.end())
       return ++(i->total);
   data.push_back({item, 1}); 
   return 1; 
 }
```

If you dont like the lambda fun:

```
template<class T>
int Counter <T> :: increment(const T& item)
{
    for(int i=0; i < data.size(); ++i)
      if(data[i].itemtype == item)
         return ++(data[i].total);
    data.push_back({item, 1}); 
    return 1;
}
```

But i think what you actually need is a `multiset` (if you dont care about the order). Something like this:

```
template<class T>
class Counter
{
    std::multiset <T> data;
   public:
      int increment(T item);
      int count(T item);
      void printSummary();
};

template<class T>
int Counter <T> :: increment(T item)
{
   data.insert(item);
   return data.count(item);
}
```